# Stack overflow when opening forms

Tags: c#

I am very new to C# so I am sorry if I use wrong terms. Here is my problem. I have 2 forms. and I want If I click the button in Form1, it shows up the Form2 by overlapping the Form1. And now, if I click the button in form2, I want the form1  overlap the form2. But I always get error "stackOverFlowException". Why did i get the error? How to resolve it? I am sorry if my question is not clear. I hope these picture can explain better about my question. 
Here is the code  for form1.

```
 public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    Form2 frm2 = new Form2();
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        frm2.Show();
    }
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        timer1.Start();
    }
    private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       frm2.Left += 10;
        if (frm2.Left >= 750)
        {
            timer1.Stop();
            this.TopMost = false;
            frm2.TopMost = true;
            timer2.Start();
        }
    }    
    private void timer2_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        frm2.Left -= 10;
        if (frm2.Left <= 535)
        {
            timer2.Stop();
        }
    }
}
```

}

and here is the code for form2

```
 public partial class Form2 : Form
{
    public Form2()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    Form1 frm1 = new Form1();
    private void Form2_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        frm1.Show();
    }
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        timer1.Start();  
    }

    private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        frm1.Left += 10;
        if (frm1.Left >= 750)
        {
            timer1.Stop();
            this.TopMost = false;
            frm1.TopMost = true;
            timer2.Start();
        }
    }

    private void timer2_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        frm1.Left -= 10;
        if (frm1.Left <= 535)
        {
            timer2.Stop();
        }
```

Comment: Please do not add code as pictures, it makes it difficult to test.

Comment: A stack overflow usually happens when you keep calling a function from within that function

Comment: It seems that form1 creates a form2, which will always create a form1, and so on

Comment: I would put your call to form2 (frm2.Show()) in the button_click event handler on form1. Then start the timer when form2 loads.

Comment: Before your next post, you will want to visit the [help] and read some of the topics there such as [Ask] a Good Question which includes advice on writing a good title

Comment: You don't need to instantiate a new form object from each form. You can just address them by their id (form name). Right now you have an endless loop with will certainly give you a stack overflow.

Comment: @HansKeﬆing : I am sorry. This is my first time...I have changed it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are creating and endless chain of opened forms.

When you first create a `Form1` object with `new Form1()`, the initialization code inside this form

```
Form2 frm2 = new Form2();
```

... is called. This in turn triggers the initialization code of `Form2`, which is

```
Form1 frm1 = new Form1();
```

This creates a new instance of this form (now you have two `Form1` instances) and calls `Form2 frm2 = new Form2();` again in this new instance (now you have two `Form2` instances). This goes on until thousands of form objects have been created and the stack overflows.

---

What can you do about it?

In `Form2` add a parameter to the constructor that allows you to pass a reference to the first form

```
private readonly Form1 _frm1;

public Form2 (Form1 frm1)
{
    InitializeComponent();
    _frm1 = frm1;
}
```

In `Form1` do this

```
private Form2 _frm2;

private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
(
    _frm2 = new Form2(this);
)
```

I.e. `Form2` never creates a `Form1`. Instead, it gets a reference to the already opened form.

---

How do you bring a form to front?

The `TopMost` property controls the behavior of a form when it is opened. Instead, use

```
_frm1.BringToFront();
```

to change the z-order afterwards.

Comment: You are welcome. This site treats his rules of conduct quite strictly and it is normal to get down voted here. Please don't get discouraged.